# Debug working in Android Studio but release apk do not install

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 and target sdk 23 with minimum sdk 21. I'm using google cloud messaging, appcompat, recyclerview and cardviews. Debug is working and the release apk is compiled and start installing but after a short while there is a message that the app is not installed..I have a working keystore and I'm not having this problem in no other app.
I'm stucked....

Comment: Do you have an app old version installed on the same device ?

Comment: You don't provide enough details about the encountered error. You'll get more accurate answers if you clearly explain what happens.

Comment: "the app is not installed" - did you get an error code? What happens? How do you know it is not installed?

Comment: The debug version in uninstalled from the phone.
The installation just ends with a message: App not installed
The debug version is working it is just the signed release apk that fails

Comment: What more details do you need. Please let  me know and post what you need.

Comment: If you run it while connected to your computer do you get anything more in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It worked after hard reset my Nexus 6 as a new device. Something seems to had been corrupt in the phone.
This has never happened to me before.